# bash insert space in last but one position of each line

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

using the `$` regex I can get last position of each line. but if I have the following:

```
12345
23456
34567
```

I need to add a space so it becomes

```
1234 5
2345 6
3456 7
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/.$/ &/' file
1234 5
2345 6
3456 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='4 1' '{$1=$1}1' file
1234 5
2345 6
3456 7
```